# Is there any plan to create GPS approaches to water areas for seaplanes?

Tags: landing, general-aviation, approach, gnss

Is anyone working on differential GPS approaches for seaplanes? They are a largely ignored resource with great capabilities for certain remote places

Comment: Given that getting into the water often means descending below terrain, and that fog likes to stay on the water longer than on land, I doubt that there will be any kind of RNAV approaches published for water. There are very few towered water airports in the world (and yes there are a couple). There's just not a good way to make sure that nobody or nothing is in the way.

Comment: They already exist. See [M57](https://www.airnav.com/airport/M57), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such plans exist. The Aarhus Harbour Seaport (ICAO code: EKAC) is planning to implement an RNAV approach to allow seaplanes to land in conditions below normal VMC, however, the authorities have yet to approve it.

Comment: Thanks! Isn’t RNAV based on VOR technology? The other issue of course is the water state, the wrong wave frequency can be quite dangerous

Comment: @Guyfacey Well RNAV can actually be based on several different types of navigation, but when RNAV is used for approach (as opposed to en-route navigation) it is usually (including in this case) based on GNSS